# Wordpress: Site Specific Plugins & Widgets

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a site specific plugin with some php that i want to be executed for the whole site, but the code doesnt seem to be applying to the PHP variables that I have in the sidebar. I'm using the PHP Widget plugin to create a widget that can execute PHP within a widget.

**In the site specific plugin I have:**

```
<?php    
$domain = ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
$cdn="http://www.domain.com";
```

**And in the sidebar PHP Widget I have:**

```
<img src="<?php echo $cdn; ?>/image1.png" width="300" height="250">
```

The plugin is loaded, and a quick `echo $cdn;` added the the bottom of the site specific plugin displays te URL at the very top of the page

When I define `$cdn;` within the PHP Widget it works fine, but I want to define the variables at the top of the site if possible.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use the [WordPress Development community](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for WordPress related questions.

Comment: Site specific plugin, doesn't sound like a plugin but a theme feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wp_header` hook to add some variable to the top of the site.

```
add_action( 'wp_header', 'my_header');
function my_header(){
   global $cdn; //add a global variable
   $cdn="http://www.domain.com";
}
```

and try

```
global $cdn;
<img src="<?php echo $cdn; ?>/image1.png" width="300" height="250">
```

Comment: i put this in the site specific plugin and loaded it, and the images in the sidebar arent loading.  Did I do something wrong?